# Need to select different column for a query which requires group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `Student` table which contains following columns:

`studentName`, `startYear`, `EndYear`, `classId`, some more columns

This table contains startYear and EndYear for students of different class.

I want to write a query to find all the students name which took maximum years (diff b/w EndYear and startYear) to pass a class.

I want following three fields in select query

```
select studentName, classId,  max(EndYear- startYear) as maxYears from Students group by classId;
```

but as group by doesn't contains studentname hence this query fails(and it make sense too).

Then I could do as : 
Putting result of following query in temp table TEMP:

```
select classId,  max(EndYear- startYear) from Students group by classId
```

and then join this temp table with student table.

```
select studentName, classId, EndYear- startYear from Student s join Temp t on s.classId = t.classId and (s.EndYear- s.startYear) = t.maxYears
```

But this doesn't look optimal to me.  I am wondering what could be other ways to do it .

Comment: Perhaps if you added some sample input and output data to your question, it would help clarify the requirement. It's a little fuzzy now.

Answer (score 0):

The following script with `correlated sub-query` should be equivalent to the `JOIN` solution and even could be converted into `JOIN` by the SQL Server optimizer.

```
SELECT studentName, classId  
FROM Students s
WHERE (EndYear- startYear) = (SELECT MAX(EndYear- startYear)
                              FROM Students sm 
                              WHERE c.classId = sm.classId)
```

Comment: This doesn't compile, as EndYear and startYear are invalid in Having clause as endYear and startyear are not part of any aggregate function or group by clause (db : SQL server )

Comment: @Ashish - You're right. Sorry about that. Will change the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, which does a self-join to fetch the row with maximum (EndYear- startYear):

```
select s1.studentName, s1.classId, s1.EndYear-s1.startYear 
from Student s1
inner join 
(
select classId, max(EndYear- startYear)
from Students 
group by classId
) s2
on s1.classId = s2.classId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM (
    SELECT  studentName, startYear, EndYear, classId, 
            DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY classId ORDER BY endYear - startYear DESC) AS Rnk
    FROM    dbo.Student
) x
WHERE x.Rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Wouldn't `RANK()` be better?  That should cover the case when more than 1 student reached the max per class.

Comment: @PM77-1: That problem could happens when `ROW_NUMBER` is used but this solution uses `DENSE_RANK`. In this particular case (`WHERE Rnk = 1`), `DENSE_RANK` and `RANK` will give the same results.